# Is it possible to write two different set of Examples in scenario outline

Tags: cucumber

The requirement is to create three users and then create a template/file to add these three users

Can I achieve this in a single scenario outline?

```
Scenario Outline: Create users and load to a template
Given I create an user <username>
And the password as <password>
And the description as <description>

Example: 
| username |   password    |    description  |

|  user1   | pwd1          | user1creation   |

|  user2   | pwd2          | user2creation   |

|  user3   | pwd3          | user3creation   |

When user create a template ??????
```

can anybody suggest how to write the template creation step and pass the usernames as parameters?

Comment: You can write multiple examples tables(U have put in Example, change it). In this case what is the requirement for multiple tables, seems like one table should be enough. You can use the dryRun = true when you run cucumber, the missing  step definitions will be automatically printed in the console. Copy and paste these. Remove dryRun when you want to be run in real.

Comment: When I run this scenario the template also would get created 3 times, but the requirement is to create 3 users and then create only one template and input the usernames to this template

Comment: If you are using Java set up a private static flag variable and set it to false in your step definition class. In whatever step this template is created check the flag value, if false create and set to true. If true then bypass template creation. If not using Java use a global variable appropriate for your language.

Comment: I need to use Examples for folder creation as well, 
like

Comment: I need to use Examples for folder creation as well, 
like
    when user creates template <templatename> with content       <contentdesc> and with <usernames> existing
    Examples:      
     |templatename |     contentdesc                |   usernames |
     |tmplate1          |    abcdefghijklmen          |   user 1         |
                                                                |   user2          |
                                                                | user 3           |

Comment: I am unable to understand as this is different from your original question. Can you edit your question with new details.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario can be written like this:

```
  Scenario Outline: Create users and load to a template
Given I have the following users:
  | username    | password    | description    |
  | <username1> | <password1> | <description1> |
  | <username2> | <password2> | <description2> |
  | <username3> | <password3> | <description3> |
When I create template for users:
  |  username   |
  | <username1> |
  | <username2> |
  | <username3> |
Then users should be added to template
Examples:
  | username1 | password1 | description1  | username2 | password2 | description2  | username3 | password3 | description3  |
  | user1     | pwd1      | user1creation | user2     | pwd2      | user2creation | user3     | pwd3      | user3creation |
```

Or as an alternative without using scenario outline:

```
  Scenario: Create users and load to a template
Given I have the following users:
  | username | password | description   |
  | user1    | pwd1     | user1creation |
  | user2    | pwd2     | user2creation |
  | user3    | pwd3     | user3creation |
When I create template for users:
  | username |
  | user1    |
  | user2    |
  | user3    |
Then users should be added to template
```

In both cases in Given step users should be defined, created in step definition and put to some shared Map, where on When step they can be extraced and added to template.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response
I think the second approach would suite to my requirement,
but here I need to define the template name  as well
    

    When I create template for users:
     | templatename     |   username |
     | template1            | user1    |
                                  | user2    |
                                  | user3    |
    Then users should be added to template

Comment: When I create a template for users
     | templatename | username |
     |  template1       | user1        |
     |                         | user2       |
     |                         | user3       |

Comment: Yes. You can add as many table columns (e.g. templateName) as you want - and then manipulate with it as with DataTables.